# find recursive solution $T(n)=2T(n/2)+n-1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I want to solve this:

$$T(n) = 2 T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) + n - 1 $$

I try :

\begin{align*}
       n &= 2^m \\
       T(2^m) &= 2T(2^{m-1}) + 2^m -1 \\
       2 ^ m &= B \\
       T(B) &= 2T(B-1) + B -1 && (1) \\
       r - 2 &= 0  \implies r = 2  \implies  T (B) = C*2^B && (h)
\end{align*}

particular : 
$$
       T(B) = AB + D \quad  \text{(A and D are const)}
$$
1:

\begin{align*}
       AB + DB &= 2(AB + DB) + B -1 \\
       A &= -1 \text{ and } D = -1 \\
       T(B) &= c \cdot 2^B -1 -B
\end{align*}
and I can't continue solving currectly 
please help me

Comment: This is the exact same text as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394962/solving-recursive-problem, which was deleted 5 minutes ago. Presumably you are the same user, posting under a different account. I don't know why you deleted the question and reposted it, but this is generally considered misuse of the site, and you should try not to do so in the future.

Comment: I think he might not have known about the edit feature. This one is significantly more cleaned up and it doesn't say it was edited by anyone else.

Comment: As for the problem, if $ 2^m = B $, that doesn't imply that $ 2^{m-1} = B - 1 $. You are moving between values and functions without taking care of the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you have an error fairly early on, so I am not going to address what all went wrong in your proof.

Here is how I would do it: Let $ k = \log_2 n $ and $ g(k) := 2^k $. Hence $$ T(g(k)) = 2T(g(k - 1)) + 2^k - 1 $$ Let $ f:= T \circ g $. Substituting this in: $$ f(k) = 2f(k - 1) + 2^k - 1 $$ Next, let, $ h(x) := 2^{-x}f(x) $. Hence, $$ h(k) = h(k-1) + 1 - 2^{-k} $$ From here, it is easy to determine a function for the case where the domain of $ h $ is the natural numbers: $$ h(k) = h(0) + \sum_{n = 1}^k 1 - 2^{-n} = h(0) + k + 1 - 2^{-k}$$ Because $ h(x) = 2^{-x} \left(T \circ g\right)(x) $, $ T(x) = 2^x h\left(g^{-1}(x)\right) = 2^{\log_2 x} \left(h(0) + \log_2 x + 1 - \frac{1}{x}\right)$, which reduces to $$ T(x) = Cx + x + x \cdot \log_2 x - 1 $$ where $ C = T(1) $.

The hard part is proving that this is the unique definition across the real numbers. While it is easy to verify that it works on such a domain, that doesn't necessarily imply uniquness.

Answer (score 0):

Equation is solved using the variable change
image :

[image]

Question after

find recursive solution
image :

[image]

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)